# Rails - Using Different primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a rails 3 application with a products model. I've been trying to find a way to use the product id number as the identifier rather that using the models default ID.

I initially tried to use the `to_param` method, however I could not get it to work correctly.

I then rebuilt my database using the products ID number instead of the primary key as so:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, :id => false, :primary_key => :prod_id do |t|
      t.string   "prod_id"
      t.string   "upc"
      t.text     "title"
      t.text     "description"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And changed my code to find/create using the prod_id. This seems to be working great, however I was hoping to find out a little more about any consequences this may have, and what the disadvantages of not using a primary key maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was hoping to find out a little more about any consequences this may have, and what the disadvantages of not using a primary key maybe.

You *are* using a primary key - it's `prod_id`. You're just not using a default setting auto-incrementing key (presumably though, `prod_id` is auto-incrementing and uniquely constrained? So you might as well have just left it as `id` for convention's sake...).

If you tell your model that it's using a different primary key, you shouldn't need to do any other configuration (or specification in associations - the `prod_id` will be picked up by reflection).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :prod_id
  ...
end
```

(different versions of Rails have twiddled with the methods for doing this... check the API for whatever you're using)

There's no magic to choosing to use a non-default primary key - you just need *some* field that uniquely identifies each row. What it's called, and what its data-type is is practically irrelevant - if you really want to, you can configure your app to use GUID strings as IDs :-)